# Create and load resources in Delphi

Tags: delphi, resources

Hi I have a program that when a button is loaded, creates a resource manually in the application itself (in this case an image) and then reads the resource to display in a timage.El problem is that it seems that creates the resource well but when I want load the resource says it can not find it when you are looking for.

The code.

```
procedure StringtoRes(const FileName: string; Inputstream: TMemoryStream);
var
  hUpdate: THandle;
begin
  hUpdate := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(FileName), True);
  try
    UpdateResource(hUpdate, RT_RCDATA, 'ID', LANG_NEUTRAL, Inputstream.Memory,
      Inputstream.Size);
  finally
    EndUpdateResource(hUpdate, False);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MemStr: TMemoryStream;
  FileName: string;

var
  RStream: TResourceStream;
  JPEGImage: TJPEGImage;
begin

  FileName := 'c:/test/test.jpg';

  MemStr := TMemoryStream.Create;
  MemStr.LoadFromFile(FileName);
  MemStr.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
  StringtoRes(paramstr(0), MemStr);
  MemStr.Free;


  Sleep(3000);


  RStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'ID', RT_RCDATA);
  JPEGImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
  JPEGImage.LoadFromStream(RStream);
  Image1.Picture.Graphic := JPEGImage;

  JPEGImage.Free;
  RStream.Free;

end;
```

as I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

In general, a running process cannot update its own resources, as its executable file is locked and not writable.  To do what you are attempting, you should move the resource to a separate DLL, then you can load the DLL dynamically via `LoadLibrary()` when you need to load its resources, and unload it via `FreeLibrary()` when you need to update its resources.

```
var
  hResLib: THandle = 0;

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ResFileName: string;
  MemStr: TMemoryStream;
  RStream: TResourceStream;
  JPEGImage: TJPEGImage;
begin
  ResFileName := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'myres.dll';

  if hResLib <> 0 then
  begin
    FreeLibrary(hResLib);
    hResLib := 0;
  end;

  MemStr := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MemStr.LoadFromFile('c:/test/test.jpg');
    MemStr.Position := 0;
    StringtoRes(ResFileName, MemStr);
  finally
    MemStr.Free;
  end;

  Sleep(3000);

  hResLib := LoadLibrary(ResFileName);
  Win32Check(hResLib <> 0);

  RStream := TResourceStream.Create(hResLib, 'ID', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    JPEGImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      JPEGImage.LoadFromStream(RStream);
      Image1.Picture.Graphic := JPEGImage;
    finally
      JPEGImage.Free;
    end;
  finally
    RStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Also, you are not checking the return value of `BeginUpdateResource()` to make sure it is actually successful before then calling `UpdateResource()`.

```
procedure StringtoRes(const FileName: string; Inputstream: TMemoryStream);
var
  hUpdate: THandle;
  bDiscard: BOOL;
begin
  hUpdate := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(FileName), True);
  Win32Check(hUpdate <> 0); // <-- ADD THIS!
  bDiscard := True;
  try
    Win32Check(UpdateResource(hUpdate, RT_RCDATA, 'ID', LANG_NEUTRAL, Inputstream.Memory, Inputstream.Size));
    bDiscard := False;
  finally
    EndUpdateResource(hUpdate, bDiscard);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks Remy , One last question, when I used my initial code without specifying a different exe, my function corrupted the exe, because he spent that? because I have seven 64-bit?